# Dataflow Bigquery-Bigquery pipeline executes on smaller data, but not the large production dataset

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dataflow

A little bit of a newbie to Dataflow here, but have succesfully created a pipleine that works well.

The pipleine reads in a query from BigQuery, applies a ParDo (NLP fucntion) and then writes the data to a new BigQuery table.

The dataset I am trying to process is roughly 500GB with 46M records.

When I try this with a subset of the same data (about 300k records) it works just fine and is speedy see below:
[image]

When I try run this with the full dataset, it starts super fast, but then tapers off and ultimately fails. At this point the job failed and had added about 900k elements which was about 6-7GB and then the element count actually started decreasing.

[image]

I am using 250 workers and a n1-highmem-6 machine type

In the worker logs I get a few of these (about 10):

```
Info
2021-04-22 06:29:38.236 EDTRefreshing due to a 401 (attempt 1/2)
```

This was one of the final warnings:

```
2021-04-22 06:29:32.392 EDTS08:[85]: GetArticles/Read+[85]: GetArticles/_PassThroughThenCleanup/ParDo(PassThrough)/ParDo(PassThrough)+[85]: ExtractEntity+[85]: WriteToBigQuery/BigQueryBatchFileLoads/RewindowIntoGlobal+[85]: WriteToBigQuery/BigQueryBatchFileLoads/AppendDestination+[85]: WriteToBigQuery/BigQueryBatchFileLoads/ParDo(WriteRecordsToFile)/ParDo(WriteRecordsToFile)/ParDo(WriteRecordsToFile)+[85]: WriteToBigQuery/BigQueryBatchFileLoads/IdentityWorkaround+[85]: WriteToBigQuery/BigQueryBatchFileLoads/GroupFilesByTableDestinations/Reify+[85]: WriteToBigQuery/BigQueryBatchFileLoads/GroupFilesByTableDestinations/Write+[85]: WriteToBigQuery/BigQueryBatchFileLoads/ParDo(_ShardDestinations)+[85]: WriteToBigQuery/BigQueryBatchFileLoads/GroupShardedRows/Reify+[85]: WriteToBigQuery/BigQueryBatchFileLoads/GroupShardedRows/Write failed.
```

In the execution details there are multiple of these:

```
2021-04-22 06:29:40.202 EDTOperation ongoing for over 413.09 seconds in state process-msecs in step s6 . Current Traceback: File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main "__main__", mod_spec) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code exec(code, run_globals) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dataflow_worker/start.py", line 144, in <module> main() File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dataflow_worker/start.py", line 140, in main batchworker.BatchWorker(properties, sdk_pipeline_options).run() File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 844, in run deferred_exception_details=deferred_exception_details) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 649, in do_work work_executor.execute() File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dataflow_worker/executor.py", line 179, in execute op.start() File "<ipython-input-81-df441d984b0a>", line 194, in process File "<ipython-input-81-df441d984b0a>", line 173, in extract_entities File "<ipython-input-81-df441d984b0a>", line 95, in get_company_sentences
```

I assume that these are from the larger texts in the dataset that can take a while to process, so after a little bit these items are processed and the next ones start.

There is also a few of these:

```
2021-04-22 06:29:40.202 EDTOperation ongoing for over 413.09 seconds in state process-msecs in step s6 . Current Traceback: File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main "__main__", mod_spec) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code exec(code, run_globals) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dataflow_worker/start.py", line 144, in <module> main() File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dataflow_worker/start.py", line 140, in main batchworker.BatchWorker(properties, sdk_pipeline_options).run() File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 844, in run deferred_exception_details=deferred_exception_details) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 649, in do_work work_executor.execute() File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dataflow_worker/executor.py", line 179, in execute op.start() File "<ipython-input-81-df441d984b0a>", line 194, in process File "<ipython-input-81-df441d984b0a>", line 173, in extract_entities File "<ipython-input-81-df441d984b0a>", line 95, in get_company_sentences
```

All of this to say, its a bit perplexing for me, and not completely intuitive - even though the service when it works is awesome.

I am executing the job from a Jupyter noteboook (not using the interactive runner, just executing the script).

Main pipeline is below:

````
p = beam.Pipeline()

#Create a collection from Bigquery
articles = p | "GetArticles" >> beam.io.ReadFromBigQuery(query='SELECT id,uuid, company_id_id, title, full_text, FROM `MY TABLE` ', gcs_location=dataflow_gcs_location, project='my_project',use_standard_sql=True)

#Extract entities with NLP
entities = articles | "ExtractEntity" >> beam.ParDo(EntityExtraction()) 

#Write to bigquery 
entities | 'WriteToBigQuery' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery('myproject:dataset.table', schema = schema,custom_gcs_temp_location=dataflow_gcs_location, create_disposition="CREATE_IF_NEEDED",write_disposition="WRITE_APPEND")  ```
````

What am I doing wrong? Is this a memory issue? Should I not be reading and writing to BigQuery like this and instead output to a file and create a  table from that? Would love some help, and sorry for the long post, wanted to provide as much context as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe late to the party but I made some tests on a BigQuery table containing 7.7M rows with strings to process of approx. 350 words.

I ran the same kind of pipeline as you:

1. Read data from BigQuery
2. Clean the strings using python `string` library
3. Using Spacy `fr_core_news_lg` model, get the lemmatized part of strings
4. Write the data back to BigQuery (in a different table)

At the beginning I got the same problem as you, number of elements/sec going down with time.

I realized it was a problem with RAM. I changed the `machine_type` from `custom-1-3072` to `custom-1-15360-ext` and went from the same profile as yours to this one:

[image: case 2]

I think Dataflow can handle big amount of rows with NLP model but you have to be sure you give enough RAM to the workers.

Also, using `number_of_worker_harness_threads=1` to be sure Dataflow will not spawn multiple threads (and thus spliting ram into the threads) is important.

You can also take a look at this [stack thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63705660/optimising-gcp-costs-for-a-memory-intensive-dataflow-pipeline), the initial problem is the same.

Last thing, my worker's CPU utilization went from:
[image: cpu not enough ram]

To :
[image]

Which is also a sign of lacking RAM.

EDIT: I ran my pipeline using the same data amount scale as you to be sure my test wasn't biased, and the results are the same: amount of RAM seems to be the key to make the job run smoothly:

[image: test 38M rows]

Comment: This is fantastic, I'm going to try this. How much RAM is in your custom machine ?

Comment: Glad to help after such a long time ! My custom machine is running 15Gb RAM (15360Mb) but maybe you will need less, I will run some tests to find the limit to cut costs. Let me know if it worked for you !

Comment: By the way, could you post a screenshot of the workers? How many did you autoscale to?

Comment: I can't really post a screenshot of the workers since there is 70 Compute Engine in total (we are limited by the in-use adresses), but I can add the code snippet defining the pipelineOptions if you want.

Answer (score 1):

I have found Dataflow is not very good for large NLP batch jobs like this. The way I have solved this problem is to chunk up larger jobs into smaller ones which reliably run. So if you can reliably run 100K documents just run 500 jobs.

Comment: Yeah I second this after experimenting. As you had said, since I'm using spacy, a smaller model would probably work for the bigger batches, but it works well enough to do in smaller pieces for my use case!