# Add column from column using Python and Spacy

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, dml

I have a BigQuery data warehouse containing all the data from a mongodb database, those data are sync once a day.

I would like to add a column to one of my table, that column is a cleaned + lemmatized version of another column (the type is string). I can't do that with DBT because I need to use the python library Spacy. How could I run such a transformation on my table without having to get all the data locally and sending 10M UPDATE on bigquery ? Is there some GCP tools to run python function against bigquery like dataflow or something like that ?

And in a more general way, how do you tranform data when tools like DBT are not enough ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Did you consider creating a view?

Comment: spaCy library can be used along with Dataflow pipelines.You can check this link for creating a [pipeline](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/beam-creating-a-pipeline) in Dataflow.
Also, as discussed in this [stack thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67213829/dataflow-bigquery-bigquery-pipeline-executes-on-smaller-data-but-not-the-large) it is better to split larger jobs into smaller ones for large NLP jobs like this.

Comment: Hi @Agudolive, if my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting and upvoting it. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [Dataflow](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow) Batch processing for your requirement since Dataflow is a fully managed service which can run a transformation on your table without downloading the data locally and spaCy library can be used along with the [Dataflow pipelines](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/beam-creating-a-pipeline). Although Bigquery and Dataflow is a managed service that can process larger amounts of data, it is always a best practice to split larger jobs into smaller ones for larger NLP jobs as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67213829/dataflow-bigquery-bigquery-pipeline-executes-on-smaller-data-but-not-the-large).

Note - As you want to add a column which is a lemmatized and cleaned version of a column in a table, it would be better to create a new destination table.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Do you have any idea on how to run Spacy pipe on DataFlow ? using the regular `nlp("text")` is not very efficient

Comment: spaCy can be used along with the Dataflow using nlp only. For efficient processing, you can disable the components which are not  required and process the text as stream using nlp.pipe and buffer them in batches. But if you are doing multiprocessing and using a large model then it creates overhead and may take time to complete the task.

Comment: Moreover, this is a new question to the original question asked. So, I would suggest opening a new thread for the same.